# Fabric: Issues running a def runtime():

Tags: python, fabric

So I'm just starting on Python and trying to craft my second script using fabric and localhost.  Following the documentation here: [*How to use Fabric in Python*](http://www.pythonforbeginners.com/systems-programming/how-to-use-fabric-in-python).

```
from fabric.api import *

env.user = 'skeer'
env.password = 'PASSWORD'
env.hosts = ['localhost']

def runtime():
    run("uptime")
    print()
```

The python console returns finished with exit code `0`.  Should I be expecting the value for uptime returned instead?  Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Do you have any output at all? Anything starting with `[localhost] ...` ?

Comment: Nope.. just the typical console:

    Process finished with exit code 0

Comment: What exact command are you using when you run fabric?

Comment: from fabric.api import *


    env.user = 'skeer'
    env.password = 'pass'
    env.hosts = ['localhost']

    def runtime():
        run("uptime")

Comment: I mean, that is likely your file contents, but how do you actually run it? Do you just run `fab -H localhost runtime` on the commandline, or something else?